# My crankshaft has reached its grinding at 30 can it be grinded further?

Tags: jimmy

My crankshaft has reach 30 can it be grinded furthe?

Comment: Hi and welcome.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean that your crank journal is already 30 thou undersize and that is the limit, then no, it cannot be taken lower.

This means either a new crankshaft or, if the cost of the crankshaft warrants it, a build-up of metal on the journal surface with subsequent machining to size and heat treatment. A very skilled and expensive process - used on special shafts...